# Working with writing and reading files in Android Studio

Tags: java, compiler-errors, filereader

I am working on a side project in android studio and need to store some long term data to a file that can be written and readable, I am able to do this outside of android studio, but when  I try to do it within, it sows a error saying

> public void onClick(View v) 'onClick(View)' in 'Anonymous class derived from android.view.View.OnClickListener' clashes with 'onClick(View)' in 'android.view.View.OnClickListener'; overridden method does not throw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException'{

I have a function in a separate file that writes to a string from a file, but when I try to access that string from one of my main view pages, its asking for an exception, but will not work with said exception, I've tried try and catch but with no success

File being initialized and written:

```
package com.example.stellarisspeciesrandomizer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DLCPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static int[] DLCArray;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.dlc_page);
        try {
            File myObj = new File("hasDLC.txt");
            if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DLCArray = new int[1];
        Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_done);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) throws IOException {
                writeToFile();
                finish();
        }});
            ImageButton aquaticsCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aquatic_checkbox);
            aquaticsCheckbox.setTag("1");
            //hello
            aquaticsCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (aquaticsCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                        aquaticsCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                        aquaticsCheckbox.setTag("2");
                        DLCArray[0] = 1;
                    } else if (aquaticsCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                        aquaticsCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                        aquaticsCheckbox.setTag("1");
                        DLCArray[0] = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            ImageButton humanoidCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.humanoid_checkbox);
            humanoidCheckbox.setTag("1");
            humanoidCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (humanoidCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                        humanoidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                        humanoidCheckbox.setTag("2");
                        DLCArray[1] = 1;
                    } else if (humanoidCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                        humanoidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                        humanoidCheckbox.setTag("1");
                        DLCArray[1] = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            ImageButton plantoidCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.plantoid_checkbox);
            plantoidCheckbox.setTag("1");
            plantoidCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (plantoidCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                        plantoidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                        plantoidCheckbox.setTag("2");
                        DLCArray[2] = 1;
                    } else if (plantoidCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                        plantoidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                        plantoidCheckbox.setTag("1");
                        DLCArray[2] = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            ImageButton syntheticCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.synthetic_checkbox);
            syntheticCheckbox.setTag("1");
            syntheticCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (syntheticCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                        syntheticCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                        syntheticCheckbox.setTag("2");
                        DLCArray[3] = 1;
                    } else if (syntheticCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                        syntheticCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                        syntheticCheckbox.setTag("1");
                        DLCArray[3] = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            ImageButton necroidCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.necroids_checkbox);
            necroidCheckbox.setTag("1");
            necroidCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (necroidCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                        necroidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                        necroidCheckbox.setTag("2");
                        DLCArray[4] = 1;
                    } else if (necroidCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                        necroidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                        necroidCheckbox.setTag("1");
                        DLCArray[4] = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            ImageButton lithoidCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lithoids_checkbox);
            lithoidCheckbox.setTag("1");
            lithoidCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (lithoidCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                        lithoidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                        lithoidCheckbox.setTag("2");
                        DLCArray[5] = 1;
                    } else if (lithoidCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                        lithoidCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                        lithoidCheckbox.setTag("1");
                        DLCArray[5] = 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            ImageButton ancientCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ancient_checkbox);
            ancientCheckbox.setTag("1");
            ancientCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ancientCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                    ancientCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                    ancientCheckbox.setTag("2");
                    DLCArray[6] = 1;
                } else if (ancientCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                    ancientCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                    ancientCheckbox.setTag("1");
                    DLCArray[6] = 0;
                }
            }

        });
            ImageButton federationsCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.federations_checkbox);
            federationsCheckbox.setTag("1");
            federationsCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (federationsCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                    federationsCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                    federationsCheckbox.setTag("2");
                    DLCArray[7] = 1;
                } else if (federationsCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                    federationsCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                    federationsCheckbox.setTag("1");
                    DLCArray[7] = 0;
                }
            }

        });
            ImageButton apocalypseCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apocalypse_checkbox);
            apocalypseCheckbox.setTag("1");
            apocalypseCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (apocalypseCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                    apocalypseCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                    apocalypseCheckbox.setTag("2");
                    DLCArray[8] = 1;
                } else if (apocalypseCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                    apocalypseCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                    apocalypseCheckbox.setTag("1");
                    DLCArray[8] = 0;
                }
            }

        });
            ImageButton utopiaCheckbox = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.utopia_checkbox);
            utopiaCheckbox.setTag("1");
            utopiaCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (utopiaCheckbox.getTag() == "1") {
                    utopiaCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
                    utopiaCheckbox.setTag("2");
                    DLCArray[9] = 1;
                } else if (utopiaCheckbox.getTag() == "2") {
                    utopiaCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkmark);
                    utopiaCheckbox.setTag("1");
                    DLCArray[9] = 0;
                }
            }

        });
            }
        public static void writeToFile() throws IOException {
            int len = DLCArray.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("hasDLC.txt");
                writer.write(DLCArray[i] + "\t"+ "");
            }
        }
    }
```

second page

```
package com.example.stellarisspeciesrandomizer;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Randomizer {
    private static int[] tall= new int[3] ;
    public static String RandomSpecies(String origin) throws FileNotFoundException {
        readFile();
        Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> originArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        String origins1 = "Prosperous Unification";
        String origins2 = "Galactic Doorstep";
        String origins3 = "Lost Colony";
        String origins4 = "Here Be Dragons";
        String origins5 = "Ocean Paradise";
        String origins6 = "Clone Army";
        String origins7 = "Necrophage";
        String origins18 = "Resource Consolidation";
        String origins19 = "Remnants";
        String origins16 = "Life Seeded";
        String origins17 = "Post-Apocalyptic";
        String origins8 = "Remnants";
        String origins9 = "Shattered Ring";
        String origins10 = "Void Dwellers";
        String origins11 = "Scion";
        String origins12 = "On The Shoulders of Giants";
        String origins13 = "Common Ground";
        String origins14 = "Hegemon";
        String origins15 = "Doomsday";
        String origin20 = "Syncretic Evolution";
        String origin21 = "Mechanist";
        String origin22 = "String of Life";

            originArray.add(origins4);
            originArray.add(origins5);

            originArray.add(origins6);

            originArray.add(origins7);

            originArray.add(origins18);


            originArray.add(origins19);


            originArray.remove(origins17);
            originArray.remove(origins16);

            originArray.add(origins8);
            originArray.add(origins9);
            originArray.add(origins10);
            originArray.add(origins11);
            originArray.add(origins12);
            originArray.add(origins13);
            originArray.add(origins14);
            originArray.add(origins15);

            originArray.add(origin20);
            originArray.add(origin21);
            originArray.add(origin22);


        originArray.add(origins1);
        originArray.add(origins2);
        originArray.add(origins3);
        origin = originArray.get(random.nextInt(originArray.size()));

        return origin;

    }
    public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("hasDLC.txt"));
        tall = new int [100];
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(tall);

    }
}
```

last page

```
package com.example.stellarisspeciesrandomizer;

import static com.example.stellarisspeciesrandomizer.Randomizer.RandomSpecies;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class RandomizerHome extends AppCompatActivity {
    String hi = "hi";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.randomizer_layout);
        ImageView originImageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.originImageView);
        Intent dlcIntent = new Intent(this, DLCPage.class);
        Button dlcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dlc_button);
        dlcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(dlcIntent);
            }
        });
        Button randomizeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.randomize_button);
        randomizeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) throws FileNotFoundException {
                String originTrue = "hi";
                originTrue = RandomSpecies(hi);

                switch(originTrue){
                    case ("Prosperous Unification"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.prosperousunification);break;
                    case ("Galactic Doorstep"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.galacticdoorstep);break;
                    case ("Lost Colony"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lostcolony);break;
                    case ("Here Be Dragons"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.here_be_dragons);break;
                    case ("Ocean Paradise"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ocean_paradise);break;
                    case ("Clone Army"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.clones);break;
                    case ("Necrophage"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.necrophage);break;
                    case ("Resource Consolidation"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.resource_consolidation);break;
                    case ("Remnants"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.remnant);break;
                    case ("Life Seeded"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.life_seeded);break;
                    case ("Post-Apocalyptic"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.post_apocalyptic);break;
                    case ("Shattered Ring"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.shattered_ring);break;
                    case ("Void Dwellers"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.void_dwellers);break;
                    case ("Scion"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.scion);break;
                    case ("On The Shoulders of Giants"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_the_shoulders_of_giant);break;
                    case ("Common Ground"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_ground);break;
                    case ("Hegemon"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hegemon);break;
                    case ("Doomsday"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.doomsday);break;
                    case ("Syncretic Evolution"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.syncretic_evolution);break;
                    case ("Mechanist"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mechanist);break;
                    case ("Tree of Life"): originImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tree_of_life);break;
                }
                System.out.println(originTrue);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: "asks for an exception" ... sorry, no idea what that means. At runtime, when things go wrong, exceptions are thrown. And when they are checked exceptions, the compiler forces you to have a try/catch block around the code invoking such methods (or to put the exception on your method signature throws list). Meaning: please step back. Do some research what exceptions are, and how to deal with them. We can't help you when you don't know the proper terms and you cant meaningfully EXPRESS what your problem is.

Comment: And note: NEVER compare strings using ==, always use the **equals()** method instead. And then: NEVER name variables like x1, x2, x3, ... Instead: learn what lists/arrays are, and how to properly use them. Starting to name things like you do there, that is just not an approach that scales.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry for the miswording, I mean that before I even run the program it says that it might throw an exception, so I should have something there in case it does. Ive tried to read what I can on the subject before asking, and when working with files outside android studio, i am able to use them fine, its just here that its not working, all Im trying to do is write a string to a file and read said string in a different file, but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to look for android studio specific examples

Comment: So, you got your answer. But thing is: it won't help you much. I am pretty sure that reading/writing files in Android is more complicated and that your current code won't work. And as mentioned before: you really lack basic understanding of java concepts. That is a common problem with people starting with Android. They think that they can learn a new programming language AND the complex Android programming model in one step. In reality: that is very hard. You should rather spent a few weeks to understand basic Java, WITHOUT the Android context. And then, when you KNOW what it ...

Comment: means when the compiler complains about this or that ... then start looking into Android. Otherwise you will spent way too many frustrating hours stumbling over **basic java** questions that have nothing to do with Android, but that are made much harder because of the Android complexity around it.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
randomizeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

What you are doing here: define an anonymous subclass of View.OnClickListener. And when you check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) for that class, it says:

```
public abstract void onClick (View v)
```

Now read the compiler message again you got. **overridden method does not throw 'java.io.FileNotFoundException'**

Thus the real answer here is: A) you have to understand what you are doing and B) you have to read compiler error messages really carefully.

Long story short, you can **not** override an inherited method and **add** checked exceptions such as FileNotFoundException to the signature of your method. So, the solution is to step back and to really learn/understand how exception handling works in Java. One possibility here: use try/catch in your  `readFile()`, catch the FileNotFoundException and *rethrow* it as (unchecked) RuntimeException. Then you do not need to have `throws FileNotFoundException` on your method signatures, and the compiler won't complain any more.